# Criar chave com mais de um arquivo e deletar tudo de uma vez

Tags: c#, app.config

Posso criar no app.config, uma chave apontando para vários diretórios e no código apontar para essa chave e deletar todos os diretórios de uma vez? Cada diretório deve ser separado por ";"? Tipo assim:

```
<add key="Dir_BD" value="C:\Teste_Zip\Destino_Teste\Temp\bd;C:\Teste_Zip\Destino_Teste\Temp\Exe;C:\Teste_Zip\Destino_Teste\Temp\js"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi. Com Get(), posso passar o nome da chave e não a posição dela. Resolvido.